# Write nested record to BigQuery using Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I want to write some nested data to BigQuery using Apache Beam and wondering if the schema I´ve created for BigQuery table is correct. Here´s how my data would look like in XML:

```
<ID>5<ID>
<Addresses>
    <Address>
        <Street>Lincoln St.</Street>
        <ZipCode>03483</ZipCode>
    </Address>
</Addresses>
```

This is how I have created my BigQuery schema to reflect the data above:

```
[{
    "name": "ID",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "Addresses",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Address",
        "type": "RECORD",
        "mode": "REPEATED",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Street",
            "type": "STRING"
          },
          {
            "name": "ZipCode",
            "type": "STRING"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
```

And this is how I am parsing the structure above to create a BigQuery `TableRow` in Java.

```
List<Address> addresses = getAddresses;

if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
    List<TableCell> repeatedRecordInstanceList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Address address : addresses) {
        List<TableCell> childObject = new ArrayList<>();

        if (address.getStreet() != null) {
            childObject.add(new TableCell().set("Street", address.getStreet()));
        } else { childObject.add(new TableCell().set("Street", null)); }

        if (address.getZipCode() != null) {
            childObject.add(new TableCell().set("ZipCode", address.getZipCode()));
        } else { childObject.add(new TableCell().set("ZipCode", null)); }
     
        repeatedRecordInstanceList.add(new TableCell().set("Address", childObject));
    }
    tableRow.set("Addresses", repeatedRecordInstanceList);
} else {
        tableRow.set("Addresses", null);
  }
```

But for some reason this is how my data looks like in BigQuery:

| ID | Addresses.Address.Street | Addresses.Address.ZipCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Lincoln St | *null* |
|  | *null* | 03483 |

It seems like for each `Address`, the `Street` and `ZipCode` and written in two iterations.

I want both `Street` and its respective `ZipCode` to be in the same row without any nulls. How can I do that? I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, a resulting object could look like this in a JSON format:

```js
{
  "ID" : "5",
  "Addresses" : [
    { "Address" : [{"Street" : "abc", "ZipCode": "1564"},
                   {"Street" : "abd", "ZipCode": "1565"}]
    },
    {"Address" : [{"Street" : "abe", "ZipCode": "1566"},
                  {"Street" : "abf", "ZipCode": "1567"},
                  {"Street" : "abg", "ZipCode": "1568"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't think you want that - there can be multiple addresses in "Address" and then multiple "Address" in "Addresses". I think "Address" shouldn't be `mode` `REPEATED` (which means it is an array). Which also means `childObject` shouldn't be ArrayList, because if you add a new element then you add a new entry to the array, no?

Comment: Thank you, @Martin Weitzmann. I worked it out after your suggestion since `Address` is always going to have exactly one instance each of `Street` and `ZipCode`.